# NSForegroundColorAttributeName key in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uicolor, nsattributedstring

I heard that NSAttributedString is added in iPhone but when I use the key NSForegroundColorAttributeName for setting the color i get an error saying "NSForegroundColorAttributeName undeclared". Am I missing anything? Please help me.

Regards

Yallappa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using kCTForegroundColorAttributeName instead.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it is worth to mention that I needed to include `#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>` to get it work.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue as BarretJ mentioned you use the kCTForegroundColorAttributeName constant. Here is an example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:countStr attributes:nil];

[attrStr addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                value:(id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]
                range:range];
```